# Is there a way to parallelize summary functions running over loop?

Tags: r, dataframe

For an input data frame

```
input<-data.frame(col1=seq(1,10000),col2=seq(1,10000),col3=seq(1,10000),col4=seq(1,10000))
```

I have to run the following summaries stored in another Data frame

```
summary<-data.frame(Summary_name=c('Col1_col2','Col3_Col4','Col2_Col3'),
ColIndex=c("1,2","3,4","2,3"))

#summary
Summary_name ColIndex
 Col1_col2      1,2
 Col3_Col4      3,4
 Col2_Col3      2,3
```

I have the following function to run the aggregates

```
loopSum<-function(input,summary){
  for(i in seq(1,nrow(summary))){
  summary$aggregate[i]<-sum(input[,as.numeric(unlist(str_split(summary$ColIndex[i],',')))])}
return(summary)  
}
```

My requirement is to run the sum as used in loopSum only in parallel, ie I would like to run all the summaries in one shot and thus reduce the total time taken for the function to create the summaries. Is there a way to do this?

My actual scenarios requires me to create summary statistics over hundreds of columns for each Summary_name in summary data.frame, I am looking for the most optimized way to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you really just taking sums of columns?  If so you'd be much better off summing each column individually and then adding those sums together.  It's hard to know what you're trying to do because your `loopSum` function doesn't work.  I'm guessing you have a custom `str_split` that you haven't included.

Comment: when you say `loopSum` is not working i hope it not throwing an error but not returning any value,(its working for me) I have added return now can you check, and thank you for the colSums idea but my problem here is not that sum is not fast enough but that i have to sequentially run it many times, I am looking for a method by which I can run all the sums in parallel which ideally should take much lesser time that running them one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it improve the running time?

```
library(tidyr)
input1 <- colSums(input)
summary1 <- separate(summary, "ColIndex", into=c("X1", "X2"), sep=",", convert = TRUE)
summary$aggregate <- input1[summary1$X1] + input1[summary1$X2]
```

Comment: Thanks ExperimenteR, how do I modify your answer if the number of columns that I have to add is not a constant as in the example I  have given, it may vary across rows, apologies for not showing this in the example

Comment: @ghub24 Can you give an example?

Comment: Thanks ExperimentaR, this is useful